# For a given product, for each store, sum daily sales at all nearby stores

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a `daily_summary` table containing columns {`order_date`, `store_code`, `product_id`, `sales`} and a `stores` table containing columns {`store_code`,`latitude`,`longitude`}, how can I:

For a given `product_id` (eg "1234"), for each `store_code`, get the daily `SUM(sales)` for the same product at nearby stores (within a 10km radius)? Output is a table with columns {`store_code`, `order_date`, `sales_at_nearby_stores`}, and I'm asking specifically for BigQuery.

My current query works, but is too slow. I'm sure there's a faster way to do it. Here's what I have so far:

```
WITH store_distances AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.store_code store1,
        t2.store_code store2,
        ST_DISTANCE(
            ST_GEOGPOINT(t1.longitude,t1.latitude),
            ST_GEOGPOINT(t2.longitude,t2.latitude)
        ) AS distance_meters
    FROM stores t1
    CROSS JOIN stores t2
    WHERE t1.store_code != t2.store_code
), nearby_stores_table AS (
    SELECT
        t1.store1 AS store_code,
        STRING_AGG(DISTINCT t2.store2) AS nearby_stores
    FROM store_distances t1
    LEFT JOIN store_distances t2 USING (store1)
    WHERE t2.distance_meters < 10000
    GROUP BY t1.store1
    ORDER BY t1.store1
), ds_with_nearby_stores AS (
    SELECT
        order_date, store_code, nearby_stores, sales
    FROM daily_summary
    LEFT JOIN nearby_stores_table USING (store_code)
    WHERE product_id="1234"
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    store_code, order_date, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(sales)
        FROM ds_with_nearby_stores t2
        WHERE t2.store_code IN UNNEST(SPLIT(t1.nearby_stores)) AND t1.order_date=t2.order_date
    ) AS sales_at_nearby_stores,
FROM ds_with_nearby_stores t1
ORDER BY store_code, order_date
```

The first part of the query generates a table with {`store1`, `store2`, and the `distance_meters` between the 2}. The second part generates a table with {`store_code`, `nearby_stores` which is a comma-separated string of nearby stores}. The third part of the query joins the 2nd table with `daily_summary` (filtered on `product_id`), which gives us a table with {`order_date`, `store_code`, `nearby_stores`, `sales`}. Finally the last unpacks the string of `nearby_stores` and adds up the sales from those stores, giving us {`store_code`, `order_date`, `sales_at_nearby_stores`}

Comment: For one thing, definitely remove your `ORDER BY` within your `nearby_stores_table` CTE.  Depending on how often you plan on using this, you might materialize your first CTE (with the cross join) as a table to see if that speeds it up.

Comment: @rtenha , This looks good. You should post it as an answer. It gives a faster performance when you remove `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what exactly is slow here, without data, and without the query explanation that is displayed after the query finishes. If it finishes at all - please add query explanations.

One of the reasons it might be slow is it computes all the pair-wise distances between all stores - creating large join, and computing tons of distances. BigQuery has optimized Spatial JOIN that is able to do it much faster using `ST_DWithin` predicate - which filters out by given distance. The first two CTEs can be rewritten as

```sql
WITH stores_with_loc AS (
    SELECT 
      store_code store, 
      ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude,latitude) loc
    FROM stores 
), nearby_stores_table AS (
    SELECT 
      t1.store AS store_code,
      ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT IF(t2.store <> t1.store, t2.store, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS nearby_stores
    FROM stores_with_loc t1
    JOIN stores_with_loc t2 
    ON ST_DWithin(t1.loc, t2.loc, 10000)
    GROUP BY t1.store
)
select * from nearby_stores_table
```

Other tweaks:

1. I used ARRAY_AGG, should be faster than converting to strings
2. Used regular join, rather than `LEFT JOIN` - BigQuery only optimized inner spatial join right now. The store always joins itself, so it is OK. We later drop the self-reference inside `ARRAY_AGG` expression.
3. Don't use `ORDER BY` in sub-queries, they don't change anything anyway.